# Private setter "set()" in Swift

Tags: swift

this is point example introduced pint structure setter getter provided by [apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) how can make only setter private

```
struct Point {
    var x = 0.0, y = 0.0
}
struct Size {
    var width = 0.0, height = 0.0
}
struct Rect {
    var origin = Point()
    var size = Size()
    var center: Point {
        get {
            let centerX = origin.x + (size.width / 2)
            let centerY = origin.y + (size.height / 2)
            return Point(x: centerX, y: centerY)
        }
        set(newCenter) {
            origin.x = newCenter.x - (size.width / 2)
            origin.y = newCenter.y - (size.height / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to be able to get the center but not set it directly? Is that it?

Comment: yes, you are right

Comment: Ok, I have undeleted my answer thinking that it might suit what you want. The other answer of using `private (set)` may also work but as indicated it works differently than what you would otherwise think. Since you don't want to be able to set the center property the best way is to use computed properties for the center. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can refine the struct Rect as follows. This will allow you to only get center but not set it.

```
struct Rect {

    var center:Point {
        let centerX = origin.x + (size.width / 2)
        let centerY = origin.y + (size.height / 2)
        return Point(x: centerX, y: centerY)
    }

    var origin = Point()
    var size = Size()
}
```

Answer (score 37):

In the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html), in the first code sample under the heading "Getters and Setters" you can see that to have a private setter, the syntax looks like this :

```
private (set) var center: Point {...
```

Some clarification :
`private` in Swift works a little differently - it limits access to property/method to the scope of a file. As long as there is more then one class in a file, they will be able to access all their contents. In order for `private` "to work", you need to have your classess in separate files.

Comment: This does not produce any warnings neither in Playground, not in real project. I do can set `Point` to `center` property.

Comment: `Private` works a little "different" in Swift - it limits the usage of property/method to the scope of the *file*. So in Playground you cannot achieve a true private property (at least I don't know how). In real projects you should keep your classes in separate files - as long as you have two classes in one file they can access all their properties/methods.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was thinking of.

Comment: As of Swift 3, `fileprivate` is used to limit accessibility to the file itself. `private` is private to the class.

Answer (score 13):

**Swift private setter**

[[Swift access modifiers]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60905233/4770877)

Solution #1 using a public function

```
struct MyStruct {
    private var a: String
    
    init(a: String) {
        self.a = a
    }
    
    func getA() -> String {
        return a
    }
}

let myStruct = MyStruct(a: "Hello World")
let a = myStruct.getA()
```

Solution #2 using private setter. In this case setter has a lower access level then geter

```
struct MyStruct {
    private(set) var a: String

    init(a: String) {
        self.a = a
    }
}

let myStruct = MyStruct(a: "Hello World")
let a = myStruct.a
```

Comment: Well explained! Thanks