# Swift 3: The difference between Public and Internal access modifiers?

Tags: swift, oop, inheritance, public, internal

I read the Apple's reference about access modifiers in Swift 3. I read also about the same on stackoverflow but I didn't get an answer as the person who asked. As I understood correctly, there are four levels:

1. Open, Public
2. Internal
3. Fileprivate
4. Private

I created the schemes for myself to understand a difference between all these modifiers and uploaded [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jm9SC.png). As you can see, there are no differences between Public and Internal modifiers.. However they're on different levels. Any idea would be appreciated!

Comment: for FilePrivate and Private different read [this blog](https://cocoacasts.com/what-is-the-difference-between-private-and-fileprivate-in-swift-3/) , you can easily understand

Comment: @SunilPrajapati thank you. The third and fourth levels are clear. The question was only about Open and Public modifiers.

Comment: read answer with example [Click Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24012515/6638996) and [Second Link](http://www.globalnerdy.com/2014/07/23/a-first-look-at-swifts-new-access-levels/)

Comment: [Swift Access Control](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diagram is just incorrect.

Public members of `A.swift` and `B.swift` are available to `C.swift` and `D.swift`. The only restriction is that classes can't be subclassed (they would need to be `open`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me, as beginner, evident however currently I feel the difference. Thank you!

Answer (score 28):

- **Internal** - This is default access specifier in swift. With this we
  can access data members and member functions in the same module
  (target).
- **Public** - This is where you can access all data members and member
  functions within same module and outside of it. But you can't
  subclass or override outside the module.
- **Open** - same as public, only difference is you can subclass or
  override outside the module.
- **Fileprivate** - As the name say's, data members and member functions
  are accessible within the same file.
- **Private** - This is where you can have access within the scope of
  function body or class.

Comment: (Swift 4+) Private: also access within extensions

Comment: private is not access within extensions .

Comment: Private: also accessible within extensions but in same file only

Answer (score 10):

Whatever you marked as **public** can be used within your app and outside of your app(module).
If you marked something as **internal** that can only be used within your app(module). This is very helpful when you're developing a library (framework), you can use **internal** to hide library structure.

Comment: Good thought. It makes me closer to understanding. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

The The Swift Programming Language book from Apple clearly explains these access modifiers:

> “Swift provides five different access levels for entities within your code. These access levels are relative to the source file in which an entity is defined, and also relative to the module that source file belongs to.
>
> *Open access* and *public access* enable entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, and also in a source file from another module that imports the defining module. You typically use open or public access when specifying the public interface to a framework. The difference between open and public access is described below.
>
> *Internal access* enables entities to be used within any source file from their defining module, but not in any source file outside of that module. You typically use internal access when defining an app’s or a framework’s internal structure.
>
> *File-private* access restricts the use of an entity to its own defining source file. Use file-private access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality when those details are used within an entire file.
>
> *Private* access restricts the use of an entity to the enclosing declaration. Use private access to hide the implementation details of a specific piece of functionality when those details are used only within a single declaration

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 3.1).” iBooks. https://itun.es/gb/jEUH0.l”

Answer (score 7):

**Swift access modifiers**

Depends on access modifier of class, function or property it can be subclassed, overrode, accessible

[image]

Access modifier can be applicable for `class`, `field`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60907642/4770877), `method`. Try to access, subclass or override this.

- Access to `field` or `method` is through a `class`
- Inheritance and **Open Closed Principle**[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66087638/4770877)

  - Extension, wrapper
  - Successor `class`(subclass) access modifier should be the same or **restrict** it(except `private` <-> `fileprivate`).
  - Successor `method`(override) access modifier should be the same or **expand** it

[[Java access modifiers]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59220073/4770877)

Answer (score 3):

```
•   Public - Can be used from any module but can’t be subclassed outside defining module (target).

•   Internal - This is default access modifier in swift. Can be accessible from the defining module (target) only.

•   Open - Can be used from any module and can be subclassed outside defining module (target).

•   Swift 4+

•   Fileprivate - Fileprivate members and functions are accessible within the same file, within the extension in same file

•   Private - Private members and functions are accessible within the same file, within the extension in same file.
```