# What's happening behind the scenes in XCTest's @testable?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, xctest

I know that

```
@testable import MyModule
```

gives ability to explore non-public members of `MyModule` from  a "test" (built with "testTarget") module `MyModuleTests`.

I need the same functionality in my "non-test" module. Not in production, just in debug mode.

My question is: do you know how to do this?

And related (I think, harder question): what magic is actually happening behind `@testable`?

Comment: *what magic is actually happening behind @testable* Seems like the compiler just doesn't enforce access restrictions on non-public members, no?

Comment: I think the only people who can answer what's going on behind the scenes are Apple employees.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer your question, for debugging purposes, you can actually use this. Let's say you have a workspace `MyAwesomeWkspace` and a project inside `MyAwesomeProject`.

Now, create a new `framework` aka `module` called `MyAwesomeModule`. Inside that module create a non-public class called `Person`.

If you try to use the class `Person` inside `MyAwesomeProject` by doing `import MyAwesomeModule` and then something like `let p = Person()` you will have an error.

But if you do `@testable import MyAwesomeModule`, the magic happens and you can now use the class.

Basically `@testable` allows you to test things that you didn't declare public. The annotation only works with `import` as you can see it [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/89c4ab0bb0de3d3aaf92f15c294c2db17a06040e/test/attr/testable.swift).

So in order to work, the target is compiled with `-enable-testing` so that you can have access to non-public members. At least based on what's [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/aee81d272f3147c0a9b610956e72a7c0772b8bcb/include/swift/Basic/LangOptions.h#L132)

Because, by default, the `debug` build configuration is compiled with `-enable-testing`, the example I showed you will work. But if you change the build config to `release`, you'll see an error saying `Module .. was not compiled for testing` since the `release` config is not built with the flag.

> The Swift access control model, as described in the Access Control
>   section of The Swift Programming Language (Swift 4), prevents an
>   external entity from accessing anything declared as internal in an app
>   or framework. By default, to be able to access these items from your
>   test code, you would need to elevate their access level to at least
>   public, reducing the benefits of Swift’s type safety.
>
> Xcode provides a two-part solution to this problem:
>
> When you set the Enable Testability build setting to Yes, which is
>   true by default for test builds in new projects, Xcode includes the
>   -enable-testing flag during compilation. This makes the Swift entities declared in the compiled module eligible for a higher level of access.
>   When you add the @testable attribute to an import statement for a
>   module compiled with testing enabled, you activate the elevated access
>   for that module in that scope. Classes and class members marked as
>   internal or public behave as if they were marked open. Other entities
>   marked as internal act as if they were declared public.

More [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html)

Late edit: One of the cool parts of swift is that is open source. So if you want to dive deep into the "magic", check it out: https://github.com/apple/swift

Answer (score -1):

**@testable import <module_name> and -enable-testing**

[[Swift access modifiers]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60905233/4770877)
[[Swift module]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67130959/4770877)

```
consumer side uses @testable import -> producer side should use `-enable-testing` flag
```

**producer side: enable `-enable-testing`**

- `Enable Testability(ENABLE_TESTABILITY)` - YES
- `Other Swift Flags(OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS)` - `-enable-testing`

**consumer side: `@testable`**

- `internal(default)` and `public` access level for **class** is **visible** for current module as `open`
- `internal(default)` access level for others(struct, enum) is **visible** for current module as `public`

If you build test schema(consumer) with `@testable` but producer doesn't include `-enable-testing` you get

```
Module '<module_name>' was not compiled for testing
```

Some experiments:

SomeModule

```
internal class SomeInternalClass {
    internal func foo() { }
}

public class SomePublicClass {
    public func foo() { }
}

internal class SomeInternalStruct {
    internal func foo() { }
}

internal enum SomeInternalEnum: String {
    case foo = "hello world"
}
```

Tests: If you omit `@testable` next errors will occur

```
import XCTest

@testable import ExperimentsTests

class ExperimentsTestsTests: XCTestCase {

    func testExample() throws {
        
        let someInternalStruct = SomeInternalStruct() //Cannot find 'SomeInternalStruct' in scope
        someInternalStruct.foo()
        
        let someInternalEnum = SomeInternalEnum(rawValue: "") //Cannot find 'SomeInternalEnum' in scope
        SomeInternalEnum.foo //Cannot find 'SomeInternalEnum' in scope
    }
    
    class SomePublicSubClass: SomePublicClass { //Cannot inherit from non-open class 'SomePublicClass' outside of its defining module
        override func foo() { } //Overriding non-open instance method outside of its defining module
    }
    
    class SomeInternalSubClass: SomeInternalClass { //Cannot find type 'SomeInternalClass' in scope
        override func foo() { } //Method does not override any method from its superclass
    }
}
```