# What does a module mean in swift?

Tags: swift

For example, I have two files called `file1.swift` and `file2.swift`.

`file1.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class A: B {
}
```

`file2.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class C: A{     
}
```

I am reading that public class can not subclassed outside of module. Here I have subclass C. I am trying to understand what does module mean here. I imported to same module UIKit for both file. So the both files are of same module? So that I can subclassed. Or both files have different module even I import the same UIKit?

Can anybody explain what is module?

Source:

Classes with public access, or any more restrictive access level, can be subclassed only within the module where they’re defined.

Class members with public access, or any more restrictive access level, can be overridden by subclasses only within the module where they’re defined.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

> A module is a single unit of code distribution—a framework or application that is built and shipped as a single unit and that can be imported by another module with Swift’s import keyword.
>
> Each build target (such as an app bundle or framework) in Xcode is treated as a separate module in Swift. If you group together aspects of your app’s code as a stand-alone framework—perhaps to encapsulate and reuse that code across multiple applications—then everything you define within that framework will be part of a separate module when it’s imported and used within an app, or when it’s used within another framework.

As the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html) indicate, the module is an application or a framework (library). If you create a project with classes `A` and `B`, they are part of the same module. Any other class in the **same project** can inherit from those classes. If you however import that project to another project, classes from that another project won't be able to subclass `A` nor `B`. For that you would have to add `open` indicator before their declarations.

Basically, if you work on a single app then you are working in one single module and unless declared as `private` or `fileprivate`, the classes can subclass each other.

**EDIT**

Let us have following class in module (project) *Module1*:

```
class A {
}
```

Since this class is not `open`, it can be subclassed only within the same module. That means that following class:

```
class B: A {
}
```

Can be written **only** in the same project, in *Module1*.

If you add *Module1* as a dependency to project *Module2*, and try to do this:

```
import Module1

class C: A {
}
```

It will not compile. That's because class `A` is not `open` (in other words it has access `public` or less) and it does not belong to the same module as `C`. `A` belongs to *Module1*, `C` belongs to *Module2*.

**Note**

`import` keyword imports a dependency module to your current module. If you write `import UIKit` in your project, you are telling the compiler that you want to use module `UIKit` in your module. `import` does not define current module. Current module is the current project.

Adding `import UIKit` at the beginning of the file does not change nor define to which module the file belongs. It just tells the compiler that in that file you want to use code from `UIKit` module.

Comment: @John it is explained there, but I added an example to explain it better, read the updated answer

Comment: I saw open class in using storyboard in playground. Storyboard and playground are different project and then to access superclass , open class used?

Comment: @John in my example, if instead `class A { }` you would use `open class A {}`, then you would be able to subclass `A` in other modules that imports *Module1*

Comment: @John Playground and project with storyboard are two different modules. However, I am not sure if the playground cannot contain a storyboard. But storyboard and classes in the same project belong to the same project

Comment: @John unless you develop a framework that is meant to be used by other people (imported as dependency) and classes thereof are meant to be subclassed by them, you are good to go with `public` or without a modifier

Comment: Thank you very much now I understand. Can you look at this file ? Why is there open class in playground please? https://files.fm/u/24xa2nhw

Comment: sources/cardController.swift file

Comment: @John I have no idea why that's an open class.. If it is defined and implemented in the same module and not used anywhere else, there's no reason for that.. Playgrounds are used to play around with code, not to implement frameworks - therefore I doubt there is any reason to use `open` in any playground code at all

Comment: Thank you very much. Accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Swift module(.swiftmodule)**

**History:**

[[#include -> #import]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59212007/4770877) -> [[Precompiled Headers .pch]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59213256/4770877) -> [[@import Module(ObjC);]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59213796/4770877) -> import Module(Swift)

There are two type of Module - folder and file

- `.swiftmodule` **folder**. Folder contains all `.swiftmodule` files for architectures and other meta information like:

  - `.swiftmodule` **file**. It is **binary** file format which contains Abstract Syntax Tree(AST) or Swift Intermediate Language(SIL) of framework's public API.
  - `.swiftdoc` - attached docs which can be revived by consumer
  - `.swiftinterface` - Module stability

[[.swiftinterface or Swift Module Interfaces]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63305234/4770877) is a next step of improving closed source compatibility

When you `Jump to Definition` of imported module actually you reviewing public interface of `.modulemap`

Binary(library, framework) can contains several modules, each module can contains a kind of submodule(from Objective-C world) thought.

```
import struct SomeModule.SomeStruct
```

These modules can have dependencies between each others.

- Module is a set of source files which solves the same problem that is why they can be grouped under the same model name.
- Module helps to group sources to reuse them
- Module helps Xcode to minimize build time(open source)(If module was not changed it should not been recompiled)

Also Module is a kind of scope which can help compiler to figure out which exactly class to use. If two modules use the same name you get

```
Ambiguous use of 'foo()'
```

It can be solved by:

```
import ModuleName1
import ModuleName2

func someFunc() {
    ModuleName1.SomeClass.foo()
    ModuleName2.SomeClass.foo()
}
```