# what is the difference between pods and modules

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

**what is the difference between pods and modules**
when i import any library either builtIn or cocoapods library both are showing Module, as u can see it in my uploaded image.
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does module mean in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426344/what-does-module-mean-in-swift)

Comment: ^^ That link explains module in Swift. Cocoapods is a package manager for installing third party libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is no such difference in it, It refers you that this framworks is added, either it is thirdparty like (Kingfisher or Moya) or it is our built in like (CoreML). So we are just use it as a framework.
Hope u get the Answer...!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Pods can slow down your build time if there are a lot of dependencies. I noticed this when using Firebase in my project. [This](https://jobs.zalando.com/tech/blog/how-the-zalando-ios-app-abandoned-cocoapods-and-reduced-build-time/?gh_src=4n3gxh1) is an interesting article about the trade offs building with pods vs. modules.

Answer (score 0):

The pod is for installation **third party** library in your project but modules is also third party library or **inbuilt** swift modules. pod is installation by pod-file of your project which you can generated by **terminal**.

Comment: but when i import any library either built in or cocoapods library both are showing Module. as u can see it in my uploaded image

Comment: if you want to use library than import pod module and otherwise you can import inbuilt module

Comment: @akbarkhan Cocoapods itself is not a known library/module for your Swift project. It is a package manager for defined library(module). It manages the installation, updates, revisions etc of defined modules. In your project, any module installed through cocoapods or builtin, it will be considered as module.