# importing a module in Swift

Tags: swift, import

I'm kicking the tires of Swift a little. I'm not using Xcode. I just have a simple .swift file and `#!/usr/bin/env swift` at the top of the file.

In the file, I have `import Blahblah` and a file called `Blahblah` in the same directory.

I get `error: no such module 'Blahblah'` however when running the .swift file.

How do I import the swift module? Is there something special I need to do?

Comment: You don't need to import local content (relative to the project), they are included automatically. `import` is used for importing third party libraries (including those provided by apple, like `UIKit`, for example)

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm not in Xcode. Trying to figure this out old school. Is there a way to tell swift to search current path dir? Perl has the "lib" directive for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a module mean in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48426344/what-does-a-module-mean-in-swift)