# Lazy let? Unswifty workaround in structs

Tags: swift, struct, properties, lazy-initialization, let

I have an immutable struct that I'm working with, and I'm trying to create a property that is *not* a computed value, however it's assignation requires the values of previously assigned properties.

(Wow mouthful).

The property I'm struggling with is `perimeter: Int`

```
// Floor made out of square tiles.
struct Floor { 

  let
  size:           (x: Int, y: Int), // How many tiles in the floor
  tilePerimeter:  Int,

  // Calculate entire floor's perimeter based on tile quantity and perimeter:
  lazy let perimeter: Int = {

    let
    t4th  = self.tilePerimeter / 4,  // Tile width / length
    sx    = self.size.x * t4th,      // All X tiles' length
    sy    = self.size.y * t4th       // All Y tiles' width

    return (sx * 2) + (sy * 2)       // Perimeter calc
  }()
};
```

Unfortunately, Swift will not let me use a `lazy let`.. So my workaround here was to just make a computed `var` with only a getter... but if this calculation took a long time (loading an image or complex math) then it would be called many times, when really it is only needed to call *once*

So my actual workaround was to just to create an initializer and assign the perimeter there... only some of my structs have MANY properties, and not creating an initializer for structs is part of the Swiftiness that I love.

I know that I could just make this a `lazy var` and instantiate the struct as `let`, but that seems confusing and error-prone.

Is there a way to do this where I can retain immutability, performance, and Swiftiness? And also, what is the reason for there not being allowed to use `lazy let`?

Comment: You can't use a `lazy let` because the semantics of `lazy` in Swift require the variable to be mutated on the first access.

Comment: That style with the `let` is ... creative?

Comment: @Alexander haha, more like "wishful", or did you mean the commas?

Comment: @Fluidity Yeah, using `let` only once and then using `commas` is really counter productive.

Comment: @Alexander how so?? Oh, I edited out this struct... i see now where I'm using 3 lines instead of 2... but there is a much longer list in my actual source.. makes folding nice

Comment: @Fluidity Because you can't copy a field in the middle and paste it somewhere else without deleting the comma at the end. Which isn't actually at the end, because of the comment, so you'll have to manually select the comma to delete it

Comment: @Fluidity Also, adding a new field in the end requires you go back to add a comma to the end of the previous line, which again, isn't truly at the end because of the comment

Comment: @Fluidity Also, if you ever want to change any of them to `var`, it'll be a total pain in the ass

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you could use `lazy var` after all:

```
lazy private(set) var perimeter: Int = {
    ...
}()
```

A *read-only* `var` gets you closer to the desired `let` semantics.

Comment: I have never seen this syntax... Is this in any documentation or book??

Comment: @Fluidity It is in all the documentation and books. :)

Comment: @Fluidity [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36148369/819340) should provide more info.

Comment: @matt I was just going through your book now looking for this.

Comment: I completely forgot read-only  vars were a thing somehow. Nice answer.

Comment: @Fluidity https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#GettersAndSetters

Comment: @Fluidity last paragraph of this section http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch05.html#_private_and_fileprivate

Comment: @matt awesome, haha.. I'm starting to think I'm crazy for getting myself into these situations... now when I try to _use_ perimeter compiler error: "cannot use mutating getter on a let instance" xD  oh my why do me and Swift not get along when I do FP?

Comment: This actually will not work with a `let` instance of Floor :) compile error when accessing `perimeter`. I suppose I will just have to use `var` for instance~!

Comment: @Fluidity tricky situation, haha! I wasn't aware of this as well :-(

Comment: hehe, I just converted the whole thing to a function and now it's just fine :) I think your answer is as CLOSE to what I wanted  via property as possible though, so I will leave it up as "solved" for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can force this to be computed only once while still using a read-only computed var by using an optional private var with a default of `nil`, much in the same way as singleton objects are implemented.

```
// Floor made out of square tiles.
struct Floor {
  private var computedPerimeter: Int? = nil

  let
  size:           (x: Int, y: Int), // How many tiles in the floor
  tilePerimeter:  Int

  // Calculate entire floor's perimeter based on tile quantity and perimeter:
  var perimeter: Int {
    mutating get {
        if computedPerimeter == nil {
            let
            t4th  = self.tilePerimeter / 4,  // Tile width / length
            sx    = self.size.x * t4th,      // All X tiles' length
            sy    = self.size.y * t4th       // All Y tiles' width

            computedPerimeter = ((sx * 2) + (sy * 2))       // Perimeter calc
         }
         return computedPerimeter!
     }
  }
};
```

Comment: perfect, will accept in 5 mins once SO lets me click the button. Much cleaner than an `Int`

Comment: this is kind of like DERP why did I not think of that :P

Comment: I'm glad to be helpful. :)

Comment: wait, doesn't your `let perimeter` need to be `var perimeter`?

Comment: you also left a comma in there in between the keywords <3

Comment: ok your code actually didn't compile even after the edits.. crap :O it sounded great

Comment: What happened? I actually don't have Xcode right now so can't check it =/

Comment: check my most recent edit suggestion .. stuck at "self is immutable" on line `computedPerimeter = (sx....`

Comment: I think adding `mutating get` should solve it. Just edited the code. This will have the minor issue of making every instance of your struct need to be stored in a `var`, though.

Comment: Swift is sort of a complex language, there's always more to learn :)

Comment: Yeah I keep going through the docs and books but there is always stuff to be forgotten :) /thumbsup

Answer (score 0):

Use an init method:

```
struct Floor {

    let size: (x: Int, y: Int), // How many tiles in the floor
    tilePerimeter: Int,
    perimeter: Int
  
    init(size:(x: Int, y: Int), tilePerimeter:  Int){
        self.size = size
        self.tilePerimeter = tilePerimeter
        
        // Calculate entire floor's perimeter based on tile quantity and perimeter:
        let
        t4th  = tilePerimeter / 4,  // Tile width / length
        sx    = size.x * t4th,      // All X tiles' length
        sy    = size.y * t4th       // All Y tiles' width

        self.perimeter = (sx * 2) + (sy * 2)       // Perimeter calc
    }
}
```